# Copy table row without values

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, clone

```
<table id="mytable">

<tr id="gonnaclone">
  <td>
      <input type="text" id ="isim" name="f1" class="large" value = "" />
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id ="komut" name="f2" checked/>
  </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I am trying to clone table row but it is coming with the same value of the cloned row.

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
var row = document.getElementById("gonnaclone");
var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
table.appendChild(clone);
```

I tried `row.cloneNode(false);` but it stopped working.

How can I make the value of clone row empty?

Comment: Why are you cloning elements which have ids?

Comment: The deep clone parameter is false by default, how has it stopped working?

I'm a bit unsure what you mean by making the value of clone row false.

Do you mean clone it but not it's children <td>'s ?

Comment: @Hrishi because i couldnt find any other method.

Comment: @ioseph when i make it false, i does not work. i dont know why. I just want to copy the row but i dont want any values which are belong to cloned row.

Comment: @ioseph When deep clone is false, only that node alone is cloned, so I guess only an empty `<tr>` is cloned, so it appears nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery you could do the following:

```
$("table").append($("table")
    .find("#gonnaclone").clone()
    .find("input").val("").end());
```

What this actually does is make a clone, find the input fields, reset the input value and append it to the table.

But to make it even better you should also remove the ID of the cloned row (otherwise you would have duplicate IDs):

```
$("table").append($("table")
    .find("#gonnaclone").clone().removeAttr("id")
    .find("input").val("").end());
```

A complete example can be found on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73uxL/1/).

---

If you also want to force the checkbox to be in a certain state (checked/unchecked) you could even make a bigger chain:

```
$("table").append($("table")
    .find("#gonnaclone").clone().removeAttr("id")
    .find("input").val("").end()
    .find("input:checked").attr("checked", false).end());
```

This actually unchecks the cloned row.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it this way

```
         var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
        var row = document.getElementById("gonnaclone");
        var clone = row.cloneNode(true);

        /**
          Will Ensure that blank entry are appended in html
        **/
        var InputType = clone.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var i=0; i<InputType.length; i++){
         if( InputType[i].type=='checkbox'){
            InputType[i].checked = false;  
        }else{
           InputType[i].value='';               
            }
        }
        table.appendChild(clone);
```

Comment: g00glen00b rised an interesting point about the id. Rather than removing it, since later you can do operations on this row, it would make sense to CHANGE the id in a manner that could allow it to be used in some eg MySQL query. @sanjeev can you kindly implement that?